# How can i search for files in a directory ending with the specific extension in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am searching for the files ending with .jpeg in a directory but there also some files which are ending like this ".jepg.e.jpeg" i need only the files which end with the one .jpeg . i wanted to do  in batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
dir /s /b /a-d *.jpeg | findstr /vi "jpeg."
```

`dir /s /b /a-d *.jpeg` will search for all `.jpg` files. where `findstr /vi "jpeg."` will exclude any file containing case insensitive `jpeg.`

you can also use it in a `for` loop if you want to do something with the files. For instance if you want to copy them from a batch file:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.jpeg ^| findstr /vi "jpeg."') do copy "%%i" "d:\destination"
```

of from cmdline directly:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.jpeg ^| findstr /vi "jpeg."') do copy "%i" "d:\destination"
```

Comment: +1 for the general approach, but you probably should use `findstr /liv ".jpeg."` so dot is interpreted as a literal. And you probably want to search for the dot before jpeg as well as after.

Comment: @dbenham, thanks for the +1. The reason I did it this way is because the only jpeg string that ends with a dot, is the one that is not the actual extension, I was considering that what if a file is `imagenamejpeg.jpeg` but you are correct, OP was very specific with his example being `.jpeg.` Thanks.

Comment: hi thanks for the solution but i am still getting the files which are ending with other format. I have two formats for Example "Abc.jpeg" and "Abc.jpeg.i.jpeg" i only need the "Abc.jpeg" but through this solution i am also getting the "Abc.jpeg.i.jpeg" as well .

Comment: @GerhardBarnard that's work Thanks can i also add multiple checks for it like "Abcd.jpeg" ,"Abcd.jpeg.i.jpeg"  "Abcd.ghk.i.jpeg"  form these three only the "Abcd.jpeg" is selected

Comment: yes. Because the string searches for anything ending with `.jpeg` but not coitain `jpeg.` the actual extension will never have an ending dot.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard  yes the multiple one is also working but on issue is that the files which contains the spaces are missing . like "Abcd efg hij.jpeg.i.jpeg " due to white spaces they are missed

Comment: but the whitespace is not an issue here because it is not at the exclusion string which is `jpeg.` The whitespace is being handled by the double quotes.